# Add reference when creating node Sensenet

Tags: sensenet

I'm working with [sensenet](/questions/tagged/sensenet) and I have something confusing when I create a node in code behind on server side, I need to add a reference field to my node but I don't know how to do that.

I tried some thing like `node["user"] = node1`

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should read it's document
I find to add a reference field, you should use some thing like this

```
node.Addreferences("User", user1);
```

user1 is one node represent for a user that you need to reference n your field

Answer (score 1):

All Content (data) in Sensenet is structured as a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) where a [Node](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Node_-_for_Developers) refers to a particular Content object as specified in it's Content Type Definition ([CTD](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Content_Type_Definition)). When a Node references another Node -- that is, it points to another location in the tree -- it can be one of two types.

1. It can either point to any node, or
2. It can be constrained to be a
   particular type, as specified in the CTD.

If you correctly assign a Reference but get an error, it is likely that you are violating the type constraint in the CTD. See examples below.

CTD for reference Node of a particular type (partial)

```
<ContentType name="Agent" parentType="GenericContent" handler="Code.ContentHandlers.Agent" xmlns="http://schemas.sensenet.com/SenseNet/ContentRepository/ContentTypeDefinition">
  <DisplayName>Agent</DisplayName>
  <Icon>Content</Icon>
  <Fields>

   <Field name="Category" type="Reference">
      <DisplayName>Agent Category</DisplayName>
      <Description></Description>
      <Configuration>
        <AllowedTypes>
          <Type>AgentCategory</Type>
        </AllowedTypes>
        <VisibleBrowse>Show</VisibleBrowse>
      </Configuration>
    </Field>

  </Fields>
</ContentType>
```

Example C# code of assigning a Node to the Category Reference defined above.

```
var path = "/Root/PathToAgentCategory";
var agentCat = Node.LoadNode(path) as AgentCategory;
myAgentNode.Category = agentCat;       // Syntax if you have a ContentHandler
myAgentNode["Category"] = agentCat;    // Syntax for the GenericContent ContentHandler
```